# modified PYTHONPATH not recognized by Anaconda Spyder

Tags: anaconda, spyder, pythonpath

I use my .bash_profile to add a directory to PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/selah/newdir"
```

In my Anaconda installation of Spyder the path I added does not show up when I type:

```
import sys
sys.paths
```

However when i do the same in Jupyter notebook, or terminal python it does show up.

Why the discrepancy? Is there a way to get Spyder to recognize my modified PYTHONPATH?

Comment: You need to start Spyder from the command line for your changes to be detected by Spyder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) You need to start Spyder from the command line for your changes to be detected by Spyder.

This is because Spyder doesn't have a way to read your environment variables when started in a graphical way.

Comment: Is it possible to explain why Spyder can't read environmental variables when started in a graphical way?  Just curious.

Comment: I think that's because variables that you define in your `.bash_profile` are not passed to applications that are not started using a shell.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. For future reference, resolved by adding path under menu “python > PYTHONPATH manager” option.

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I rebooted spyder.