# Cannot seem to get GDAL to import into anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed anaconda onto my system and tried numerous ways of installing GDAL each time on Spyder it gives me the same response: `ImportError: No module named gdal`

I wrote the program just as follows:

```
import gdal
```

Ran it then that error

Tried:

```
import osgeo import gdal
```

same issue.

So then I installed the Anaconda prompt. And it seemed to install anaconda when I typed in:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

I went back to Spyder and got the same error.

Any ideas of why this is happening?

In the Anaconda prompt I wrote: gdalinfo --version
And got back:

```
GDAL 2.2.4, released 2018/03/19
```

All seems up to date except when I run in Spyder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be related to the environment variables used by Spyder, so you can try to execute spyder from the command line or compare and add the missing paths in Spyder.

- To execute from command line:

  ```
  spyder
  ```
- To see missing paths:

  Enter to a Python command line and run this:

  ```
  import sys
  sys.path
  ```

  Then in Spyder under menu `Tools > PYTHONPATH manager` option add the path

Note: You should import `gdal` like this `from osgeo import gdal`, `import gdal` is deprecated

Hope it helps!

References:

- [modified PYTHONPATH not recognized by Anaconda Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086454/modified-pythonpath-not-recognized-by-anaconda-spyder)

Comment: Thank you. Not sure I totally understand. In what command line do I enter it, the standard win-10 one or python command line? Also I tried both win-10 command line and python command line, each time I typed spyder it said 'spyder' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: I'm sorry, I assume you were using Linux, navigate to Spyder installation folder and then type spyder and press enter, this should starts the ide or try from python command line "from spyder.app import start" and "start.main()"

Comment: When I am in the python command line I typed: from spyder.app import start. Tell me: ImportError: No module named spyder.app

Comment: How did you install Spyder?

Comment: Just installed alongside Anaconda from their website.

Comment: Now when I run command prompt it tells me: 'gdalinfo' is not recognized as an internal or external command. I am lost on this.

Comment: I went to tools > PYTHONPATH manager > +Add path > C:\Program Files\GDAL

Comment: When I go to run it still says: ImportError: No module named gdal

Comment: And when I write, from osgeo import gdal, then it says ImportError: No module named osgeo

Comment: I tried to reproduce it, from Anaconda Prompt I executed `conda install gdall` `conda install spyder` and runned `spyder`, in Spyder imported gdal as mentioned (`from osgeo import gdal`) and works fine

Comment: You can try to create a new conda environment to "start from zero" `conda create --name gdaltest`, activate the environment `conda activate gdaltest` and there install again gdal and spyder and execute spyder, to deactivate the environment use it `conda activate gdaltest`

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked out by changing settings in the spyder interface:

*Tools → Preferences → Python interpreter:* `C:/ProgramData/Anaconda2/envs/gdal/python.exe`

After that change, spyder asked to run `conda install ipykernel cloudpickle` in the current environment. I did it and it worked. Another solution might be adding the same path (also in the spyder interface): *Tools → PYTHONPATH manager*.